# Empty Popover with Tableview and Static Cells

Tags: ios, ipad, uipopovercontroller, popover

I have a tableview setup with some static cells that I display in a popover.  The problem is that the popover is always empty and I can't seem to figure out why.  I've removed all of the data methods in my tableviewcontroller so that isn't the issue.  Can anyone see any problems in the code below or point me at something I may be missing?  Thanks!

TableViewController code:

```
@implementation ICAMDisciplineTableViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;
   self.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(400.0, 400.0);
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self.delegate disciplineTableViewController:self
                           didSelectEnumItem:indexPath.row + 1];
}

@end
```

Code that shows the popover:

```
-(void)fireDisciplinePopOver
{
    ICAMDisciplineTableViewController *popoverTable = [[ICAMDisciplineTableViewController alloc] init];
    self.popOverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc]initWithContentViewController:popoverTable];
    self.popOverController.delegate = self;
    popoverTable.delegate = self;
    [self.popOverController presentPopoverFromRect:self.disciplineTextField.frame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Does `ICAMDisciplineTableViewController` have a .xib file? If so, you need to call `initWithNibNamed:bundle:`

Comment: Are you certain that your UITableViewController works when not in a UIPopover? Try -presentModalViewController first to see if this is actually an issue with the popover.

Comment: It's built on Storyboard. Thanks for the reply though.

Comment: I can display the tableviewcontroller fine in a modal.  It's only empty when it's in the popover.  Very frustrating!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your fireDisciplinePopover do this to get your `UIViewController` from your Storyboard:

```
  UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard"
                                                                 bundle: nil];

  ICAMDisciplineTableViewController *popoverContent = (ICAMDisciplineTableViewController*)[mainStoryboard
                                                                             instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"ICAMDisciplineTableViewController"];
```

Make sure to set the Storyboard ID for that `UIViewController` in your Storyboard-- I just set it to your view controllers name above.

Comment: That did the trick.  Thank you! Any idea why wouldn't it display the content using the alloc/init?  My code above works great for UITableViewControllers that are populated with a FetchedResultsController.

Comment: @Majkeli When you create your view in Storyboard; the .h/.m files have no idea about that view you created-- your Storyboard connects a view to its class. This is why you must grab an instance of the UIViewController from your Storyboard as it gives you the view & the code. Your popover was blank because yes you had a valid instance of your view controller, but it had not idea about an associated view in the storyboard. Hope that makes sense